# Cannot build dart project due to custom dependencies doesn't support sound null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I have been studying over dart projects and tesing dart packages and interdependencies.
I created a Dart Project called console_full_project, where within the project i made a package called calculator and added it to main projects pubspec.yaml file.

main project's pubspec.yaml codes are

```
name: console_full_project
description: A sample command-line application.
version: 1.0.0

publish_to: none

# homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0-266.8.beta <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  calculator:
    path: "packages/calculator"

dev_dependencies:
  lints: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.16.0
```

and my packages pubspec.yaml file's codes are

```
name: calculator

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0<3.0.0"

dependencies:
  lints: ^2.0.0
```

While a tried `dart run`  command in my terminal

It resulted

Failed to build console_full_project:console_full_project:
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:calculator

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this problem.

1. Decrease **project level** `environment` variable in `pubspec.yaml` file to  `2.10.0`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"
```

2. Try to run the project with the following command in **project level directory**

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Note: The following options might not be available if the package is out of your control.

3. (Optional) Increase **package level** `environment` variable in `pubspec.yaml` file to  `2.12.0` or above

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

4. (Optional) Use dart migration tool in your **package level directory** with
   `dart migrate` command

Comment: My pleasure. You can mark the answer the question as solved if your problem is solved.

Comment: You may want to point out that #2 (optional #3) is the only constructive way to go forward, all others are fixes for when #2 is out of your control.